# Reading array returned by c function in ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I've got some C code, which I'm trying to access from ctypes in python.  A particular function looks something like this:

```
float *foo(void) {
    static float bar[2];
    // Populate bar
    return bar;
}
```

I know this isn't an ideal way to write C, but it does the job in this case.  I'm struggling to write the python to get the two floats contained in the response.  I'm fine with return values that are single variables, but I can't work out from the ctypes docs how to handle a pointer to an array.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you should not return a variable on stack, you should malloc one then return.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Specify restypes as `[POINTER][1](c_float)`:

```
import ctypes

libfoo = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')
foo = libfoo.foo
foo.argtypes = ()
foo.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)
result = foo()
print(result[0], result[1])
```

Comment: That works, but would it be possible to know the size of the returned array? E.g., `len(result)` doesn't work in this case. To fix it, I tried `foo.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float * 2)` but it doesn't work as the return values appear to be wrong, although `len(result)` is correct.

Comment: @OlivierMichel, How about [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)?

Comment: @OlivierMichel, You may need to handle pointer (something like accessing `.contents`); https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#pointers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @falsetru, believe I found a somehow better solution, which takes into account the fact that the C function returns a pointer to two floats:

```py
import ctypes

libfoo = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')
foo = libfoo.foo
foo.argtypes = ()
foo.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float * 2)
result = foo().contents

print('length of the returned list: ' + len(result))
print(result[0], result[1])
```